# client - server architecture structure (with node js) - where to put the index.html file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, architecture

I have built a server client app (nodejs - on the server, angular - on the client).

I used to have all my code in one project (one folder) but then I figured it makes more sense for me to divide it, by logic, to a server folder and to a client folder.

I aspire for disconnecting all of the dependencies between the server code and the client code, in the sense that each side can stand alone by its own.

**Questions:**

1. where do I put the index.html?

it is obviously related to the client side but the server (expressJS) is loading it when the server.

2. lets says I put this index.html file in the client folder like in the picture below..

how can I make the server.js be aware of it?

this code doesn't work:

```
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/',express.static(__dirname));

app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname,
    'node_modules')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '../client/index.html')));
});
```

[image]

Comment: did you try `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/../client'));` ? You don't have to declare `app.get('/', ....`

Comment: first of all thanks. it worked... 2nd - the name index.html is defualt? what if I want to use my_index123.html?

Comment: I didn't understand you want to access the url localhost:8080 and get the page `my_index123.html` in response ? In that case, why don't you rename your file by index.html ?

Comment: Yes "index.html" is default, express static will check for a "index.html" file in the `public` folder.
If you want to route "/" to "my_index123.html, i'd have a look at a setup more like this:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-deliver-html-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually with express apps, you would have a "public" folder that contains your client assets, index.html being one of them.

```
app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

then, run the node server, open a browser and point it to that server and express will serve up "index.html" from the "public" folder.

**Steps to fix**

- Rename `client` folder to `public`
- Drag `public` inside `server` folder so its like `server/public`
- change `app.use('/',express.static(__dirname));` to `app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));`

**Please note**: `app.use('/',express.static(__dirname));` should be avoided, you're serving up your whole server directory to the public.

If you want to have a better look at project layouts.
Have a look at yoeman.io, specifically it has project templates for express.

http://yeoman.io/

> Yeoman helps you to kickstart new projects, prescribing best practices
>   and tools to help you stay productive.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out. one more question - my client (angular) uses dependencies in addition to the npm modules the server (the client modules realted just for the client code, i.e. angularAuth library). should I have npm modules  directory (or maybe bower modules) in the client as well?

Comment: :D you have 2 options: 1, create a "bower.rc" file that sets install directory to  `public/bower_components` and serve user assets from there. or 2. add another express static line to serve assets from `bower_components`
either is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/',express.static(__dirname));

//it will serve all files in client directory under the '/' route        
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client'));
});

//and the client side scripts installed through npm will be served under '/scripts' route
app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/node_modules')))
```

It will be good to serve the client side modules in separate folder i.e. to have `node_module` folder in the `client` directory as well, there you should install all modules which should be load from the client side. Besides this the `client` folder seems public, so it is worth to serve the whole folder.

If you want to install modules for client side then go to `'/client/node_modules'` directory in the terminal and run the npm. So if you are linux, then:

1. `cd client/`
2. `npm init`
3. `npm install YOUR_DESIRED_MODULE`

In case of modules for server side install modules in your root directory

Comment: Thanks, but if I will put the node modules in the client what about all the modules that belongs to the server (i.e. mongodb..)?

Comment: install that modules in the root directory